# How to convert game object world position to hex grid cell coordinates?

Tags: unity, hexagonal-grid

I have a hex grid and a game object, let's say it's the player. What I want to do is know on which cell the player is on based on his world position, this would be easy on a simple grid but on a hex grid it's giving me a headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this useful and complete article may help you :
https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

There's 4 different possibilities for implementing an hexagrid. Depending on your "offset coordinates". For each type the article explains how you can convert position to hex coordinate.

And good luck, I had to implement such system too before this article ever existed ^^

Comment: Thank you, i already checked this article but i think i missed the part where it shows how to convert position to hex coordinates, i'll check it again hopefully i'll find my answer :)